Parameter tuning with Slurm, Optuna, PyTorch Lightning, and KFold
With the following toy script, I am trying to tune a hyper-parameter of "learning rate" for a perceptron with "Optuna" and 5-fold cross validation. My cluster has multiple GPUs on each node, so I am using "Slurm" as the work load manager and "ddp" for distributed computation. However, this same script behaves differently when launched by "Slurm" versus running directly on a computational node.
import torch
import pytorch_lightning as pl
import numpy as np
from optuna import Trial, create_study
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

class DummyModel(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, lr):
        super().__init__()
        self.linear = torch.nn.Linear(5000, 1); self.lr = lr

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.linear(x)

    def calculate_loss(self, batch, mode):
        x, y = batch
        y_hat = self(x)
        loss = torch.nn.functional.mse_loss(y_hat, y)
        self.log(mode + '_loss', loss, sync_dist=True, on_step=False, on_epoch=True)
        return loss

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        return self.calculate_loss(batch, mode='train')

    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        self.calculate_loss(batch, mode='val')

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=self.lr)  
        return optimizer 

def objective(trial: Trial, x, y):
    learning_rate = trial.suggest_float("learning_rate", 1e-5, 1e-1, log=True)
    loss = []
    for i, (trn_ids, val_ids) in enumerate(KFold(n_splits=5).split(X=x, y=y)):
        print(f"train and val ids are {trn_ids}, {val_ids}")
        trn_dt = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(x[trn_ids], y[trn_ids]), batch_size=1000)
        val_dt = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(x[val_ids], y[val_ids]), batch_size=1000)
    
        model = DummyModel(lr=learning_rate)
        trainer = pl.Trainer(devices=2, accelerator="gpu", strategy="ddp", max_epochs=10, log_every_n_steps=5)
        trainer.fit(model, trn_dt, val_dt)
        loss.append(trainer.callback_metrics["val_loss"])
    return np.mean(loss)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("===Script Start===")
    batch_size = 1000; x = torch.randn(batch_size*100, 5000); y = torch.randn(batch_size*100, 1)  
    study = create_study(direction="minimize")
    study.optimize(lambda trial: objective(trial, x, y), n_trials=5)

If launched by Slurm with srun --gres=gpu:2 python ./ttt.py:
The "===Script Start===" is printed out once, but the script only uses one GPU (verified by nvida-smi).
If launched locally on a computational node, simply with python ./ttt.py:
The "===Script Start===" is printed out twice, but the script also uses two GPU.
So what's the cause of these different behaviors? How can I launch it by Slurm but also use two GPUs?

It indentation isn't format probably.

Thanks a lot! I did not notice that and now it is corrected.
